# Why cant the code print the elements of this 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, matrix, cout

Ok so i have written this code to print all elements of an 2D array . But , surprisingly , nothing is printed on the screen. Here's the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

char ans[1001][1001];



void display_ans(int row,int col)
{
    for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            cout<<ans[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    memset(ans,'$',sizeof(ans[0][0])*2*2);
    display_ans(2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

There is nothing printed on the screen.This is really awkward.I cant understand whats wrong with the code.

Comment: First of all, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Second thing, remember that array indexes are *zero based*.

Comment: Lastly, remember that your array `ans` is an array *of arrays*. That means `ans[0][0]` will not be next to `ans[1][0]` in memory.

Comment: Here's an idea. Print the entire array, and you'll see exactly where your misunderstanding lies

Comment: `1001`that is an unusual value. Do you think you always have to spare one?

Comment: @Some programmer dude "Lastly, remember that your array ans is an array of arrays. That means ans[0][0] will not be next to ans[1][0] in memory."  Is it got to do something with memset function ? I really cant understand why you said that .

Comment: @PiyushSoni `memset(ans, '$', sizeof(ans[0][0]) * 2 * 2);` is the same as `ans[0][0] = '$'; ans[0][1] = '$'; ans[0][2] = '$'; ans[0][3] = '$'; `

Answer (score 4):

Lets take a look at a somewhat smaller array of arrays look like in memory:

```
char a[3][3];
```

This will be something like

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[0][2] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | a[1][2] | a[2][0] | a[2][1] | a[2][2] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

A call like `memset(ans,'$',sizeof(ans[0][0])*2*2);` will set the memory for the four first memory locations. That is with our example above it will be `a[0][0]`, `a[0][1]`, `a[0][2]` and `a[1][0]`. The memory for e..g `a[2][1]` will not be touched.

For your array, `ans[0][0]` is the first element, followed by `ans[0][1]`, and all the remaining 999 elements of `a[0]` before `a[1][0]`.

That leads to the elements that will be set by your `memset` call will be `ans[0][0]`, `ans[0][1]`, `ans[0][2]` and `ans[0][3]`. The rest of the memory for `ans` will be all zero.

***And*** since you print using one-based indexes, you print `ans[1][1]`, `ans[1][2]`, `ans[2][1]` and `ans[2][2]`. Which are all zero.

---

Oh I see that you updated your question, which means you will print `ans[0][0]`, `ans[0][1]`, `ans[1][0]` and `ans[1][1]`. The first two characters should be `'$'`, while the second two will still be zero.

Comment: all that OP had to write is `memset(ans, '$', sizeof(ans) );`

Comment: @Swift Well since it's C++ I would rather recommend e.g. `std::fill_n(&ans[0][0], sizeof ans , '$');` :)

Comment: I did not said that he SHOULD have write this, although for some C++  imlementations memset used on char array is still the fastest way to do this (fill is significantly slower). All i hinted at is that OP code looks like an example of overcomplication caused by misconstrued view or ignorance. I totally agree otherwise

Comment: Its working fine now. I just replaced the sizeof(ans)*2*2 by sizeof(ans).Thanks.